# Losing referrer set in HTTPS 302 redirect response header

Tags: http, redirect, referrer, http-status-code-302

I have an app that is entered from a 302 redirect, like so:

1. `arbitrary site` User clicks link (https://referrer.example.com?query)
2. `https://referrer.example.com?query` 302 Redirects to
   (https://myapp.example.com)
3. `https://myapp.example.com` Wants to get
   "https://referrer.example.com?query" from `document.referrer` but instead gets site from [point 1]

Within the app I want to verify the intermediate (redirecting) referrer [point 2], and even though this is setting a `Referrer` header in its response, the end page is getting the previous page as its `document.referrer`.

I'm somewhat unsure whether the usage of redirects we're attempting is out of line with their intended purpose, or if browser referrer behaviour is being buggy, or if there is header information we're failing to set in the intermediary. I suspect it could be the former but interested in any insight that explains what's going on, or any documentation that explains the results I'm seeing (i.e. explains redirect/referrer interaction).

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Anyone has enough reputation to start a bounty? Such an interesting question.

Comment: @Oliv Utilo - any luck???